# SWD vs ST-LINK on STM32F4 Discovery board

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, debugging, swd, stm32f4-discovery

Why do we have 2 connectors namely CN2 (SWD) and CN3 (ST-LINK) on STM32F407 Discovery board? Are not they the same thing?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not the same.

The pair of jumpers on CN3 connects the ST-Link to the target device (i.e, the STM32F407 located on the Discovery board).

When those jumpers are removed, the SWD pins on CN1 can be used to connect the ST-Link to another target device.

Comment: ok i got it now. If i have to make my custom pcb using STM32F407 MCU then which connector should i use in it to flash the mcu.. CN2 or CN3?

Comment: If i don't want to use the on-board ST-Link circuit of this discovery board but instead i want to use a ST-Link device to flash the on-board 'F407 MCU then how would that be possible?

Comment: 1) Use CN2 to connect the onboard ST-Link to other devices. CN3 is only for jumpers. 2) Connect the external ST-Link to the appropriate pins on the MCU headers (P1 and P2).